# Why aren’t they any statues attributed to Moshe when he was prince of Egypt?

Tags: history

Why aren’t they any statues attributed to Moshe when he was Prince of Egypt? Did the Egyptians destroy them after the exodus? Perhaps there isn't any because this would be in violation of the Decalogue: “Thou shalt not make unto thee a graven image, nor any manner of likeness”?

Comment: Maybe there are? Would you recognize him?

Comment: @doubleaa maybe just his name

Comment: Relevance on this site? Seems to be more of an Egyptian history question than a Jewish / Judaism one.

Comment: We have no record of Moshe being a sculptor, so why would any statues be attributed to him?

Comment: Voting to close as not a question about Judaism.

Comment: Mmm, seems to me that your right. This question is more of Egyptian history than it is of Judaism in and of its self.

Comment: @joshk - that's exactly what I was thinking also, when I read the term "attributed to" instead of something like" alleged to be a representation of". :)  Maybe he whacked the Egyptian with hammer and chisel. One of the later historians identified Moses with a guy named Osarsiph, maybe statues exist using that name(??)

Comment: Assuming there were (which I don't know if there would be), why would you think they would have survived the past 4,000 years? That's a long time. We don't have very much from that time period anyway. It's a miracle we have _anything_ from Ancient Egypt.

Comment: Statues do exist from 3,000 yrs back. As far as Mosh, it’s possible that paintings of statues could had existed. The Egyptians might have torn them down after the events of th exodus.

Comment: @Gary it would be pretty awesome, though, if the guy who brought us "you shall make no graven images" had been a sculptor in his youth.

Comment: @TurkHill I didn't say statues didn't exist that far back. I said that even if there were statues of Moshe there's a high chance we wouldn't have them anymore. Not everything survives to be eventually studied by archaeologists.

Comment: I agree, Plus the Egyptians might have torn them down after the events of the Exodus.

Comment: Note that one of the kings of egypt (ruled for 17 years) was all but forgotten until someone uncovered a whole city that he had built https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhenaten.

Comment: We actually have archaeological records of not one, but *two* people in the court of Ramases II named Moshe. (source: Digging Through the Bible, Richard Freund). We have no way to know if either is Moshe Rabbeinu.

Comment: It is very possible that at least one of them is Mosh Rabbeinu if not both. That is our statue!

Answer (score 6):

When discussing Biblical Archeology, there are those who try and look at the issues with a "minimalist" view. Usually, they assume that we have a vast knowledge of ancient Egypt and have found much of the artifacts etc. Therefore they ask:

"If X is true, why don't we find Y artifacts?"

However, this is called in logical terms an "Argument from Silence". An argument from silence is usually a very weak attempt at proving anything because it bases itself upon what we did not find as opposed to what we did find.

Example:

Regular Argument: We found a pyramid with Pharoah Tutnik's name engraved in the burial chamber. Therefore, this must be the grave of Tutnik and he did exist!

Argument from Silence: We have been digging here for days and we did not find any tombs with Pharoah Tutnik's name. Therefore he did not exist!

The second argument is very weak.

Here are some reasons:

1. Keep digging. :)
2. Tutnik was an unpopular king, so he didn't rate a fancy tomb.
3. Tutnik believed in a different Egyptian diety that asked its followers to be cremated and scattered upon the Nile.
4. Tutnik's throne name on the 3d tomb over there is engraved "Zorba of Upper and Lower Egypt" but we didn't have enough evidence to connect Zorba with Tutnik as one and the same guy.
5. Tutnik died in a foreign war.

Etc. Etc.

Furthermore, the idea that we are in possession of all the artifacts of Egypt by now is just not true. Archeology is only about 200 years old if that. The amount of things found is directly related to the great sums of money granted by the rich and governments to fund expeditions as well as the extreme amounts of time it takes to uncover things safely and to know where to look.

There is a lot more of Egypt to discover which makes any argument from silence neutral and weak at best.

Finally, regarding Moses, the Torah says that "Prince" Moses fled Egypt after killing the Egyptian taskmaster. The Medrash even says that the current Pharoah at the time tried to execute Moses for the killing.

He went from Prince to Outlaw. (Remember, the king knew he was adopted, not blood.) So, why would a ruling king want to make a monument to an escaped con? This is especially true when many kings at the time feared their own children and relatives as potential usurpers to the throne. How much more so to fear an adopted prince might claim legitimacy against his royal brother who would be the rightful heir? You don't make tribute statues to such people if you know what's good for you.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Very enlightening! You answered my question: )

Comment: TY. We hope to see you around asking more questions. :)